# Scriptmanager not loading properly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, timeout, scriptmanager

I want to show a div after an action.
For now i will just use a button click event.

this is my jquery function:

```
function hideMessageBlock() {
        $('.alert').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    }
```

i also tried this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('READY to animate');
        function hideMessageBlock() {
            $('.alert').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
```

in my code behind i have the following code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            alertSuccessBlock.Visible = true;
            lbl_alertSuccessBlock.Text = "Animate this block with timeout!";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptManager1", "hideMessageBlock();", true);
        }
```

in the aspx i have declared a scriptmanager right after the scripts i use (bottom of the page before form and body closure):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

The Error that i am receiving is : ReferenceError: hideMessageBlock is not defined
The function is called before the whole jquery script is loaded (just guessing)

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I have already solved the issue.

I had to move the function definition outside of the document.ready callback ($(function() { }):

Comment: If you declare a function, inside another function then its scope is within that outer function only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved the issue. I had to move the function definition outside of the document.ready callback